# environment variables sent to a JAR file are accessible in System.getProperty, but in System.getenv

Tags: java, environment-variables

I invoke my code like so:

```
java -Dconfig=val -jar file-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Inside the Java code, I can only obtain the "config" parameter if I use:

```
System.getProperty("config");
```

Is there a way to send environment variables to a JAR so that they will be available using

```
System.getenv("config") ?
```

Maybe send the environment variables in some other way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use your operating system's way of setting environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access `config` as an environment variable via `System.getenv`, you need to make sure that such environment variable is set before you run your Java app:

- Windows

```
> SET config=val
> java -jar file-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

- Linux

```
$ export config=val
$ java -jar file-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```